# Howto install package language-support-en

Tags: 12.04, locale

I can not install language-support-en. This is what I got after trying. Please help:

```
Generating locales...
  en_AG.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_AU.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_BW.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_CA.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_DK.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_GB.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_HK.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_IE.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_IN.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_NG.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_NZ.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_PH.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_SG.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_ZA.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_ZM.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_ZW.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.

sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
Generating locales...
  en_AG.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_AU.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_BW.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_CA.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_DK.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_GB.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_HK.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_IE.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_IN.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_NG.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_NZ.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_PH.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_SG.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_ZA.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_ZM.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_ZW.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.

sudo apt-get install --reinstall language-support-en
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package language-support-en
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to dash and type

> language support

search and install

Answer (score 0):

There is no package with that name.

But normally you don't need to bother about the names of the language support packages; *Language Support* automatically installs the files corresponding to the installed languages.

Just launch Language Support: System Settings... -> Language Support.

If asked whether you want to install additional language support, click *Install*.